# ¿Como saber el el día ,mes y año según el nombre del Día ? Con JavaScript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente :

Tengo un input text con valor Lunes y quiero usar ese valor para 
hallar la fecha en formato yyyy/mm/dd.

**Por ejemplo :**

**Hoy estamos  2018/10/18 dia Jueves  y enviaría el valor del input (Lunes) a una función   donde el valor que me entregaria seria  la fecha del lunes de la semana actual que  seria  2018-10-15**

Tengo esta funcion pero de forma inversa osea envio el numero del dia y me entrega el nombre del dia :

```js
    var f = new Date();
    var dia=f.getDate();
    var mes=f.getMonth() +1;
    var anio=f.getFullYear();
    verificar_diaSemana(dia, mes,anio);
    
    function verificar_diaSemana(dia,mes,anio){
    var dias=["dom", "lun", "mar", "mie", "jue", "vie", "sab"];
    var dias=["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes",      "Sábado"];
    var dt = new Date(mes+' '+dia+', '+anio+' 12:00:00');
    alert(dias[dt.getUTCDay()]);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**¿Alguien podría ayudarme a resolver este problema?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para todos los dias de la semana:

```js
fecha_diaSemana("Lunes");
    
function verificar_diaSemana(dia,mes,anio){    
    var dias=["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];
    var dt = new Date(mes+' '+dia+', '+anio+' 12:00:00');
    return dias[dt.getUTCDay()];
}

function fecha_diaSemana(day) {
    var dias=["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];
    var f = new Date();
    var dia=f.getDate();
    var mes=f.getMonth() +1;
    var anio=f.getFullYear();
    
    var hoy = verificar_diaSemana(dia,mes,anio);
    
    var d = dias.indexOf(day);
    var h = dias.indexOf(hoy);
    
    if (d > h) {
      dia += (d - h);
    } else if (d < h) {
      dia -= (h - d);
    }
    
    var dt = new Date(mes+' '+dia+', '+anio+' 12:00:00');
    console.log(dt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si gustas puedes utilizar la siguiente función:

```js
 function getMonday(d) {
          d = new Date(d);
          var day = d.getDay(),
              diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1); 

          return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
        }

        console.log(getMonday(new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10));
```

Agregué el `.toISOString().substring(0, 10)` para dar el formato yyyy-mm-dd. Espero te ayude.

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156434/javascript-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-from-current-date